# Can I insert any word/adverb between the noun and the relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, adverb-position

In the following two sentences, should I always move "yesterday" and "very much" to other places or can I leave some short ones in between the noun and the relative clause?

> 1. I visited my mother yesterday who was ill.
> 2. I like the teacher very much who is a friend of my mother.

Answer (score 2):

Although in speech people do that often, if you can avoid it, it is better not to separate the noun or noun phrase from its relative pronoun. Your sentence 1. sounds clumsy, and it is much better to say:

> ***Yesterday*** I visited my mother, who was ill.

Your sentence 2. is also awkward, and could be formulated as

> I like ***very much*** the teacher who is a friend of my mother.

But even this result does not sound too natural.

However, there are better ways of saying the same: you can put a full stop or connect your clauses by a subordinator such as *because*. Your sentences will flow much better.

> I visited my mother yesterday. She was ill.
> I visited my mother yesterday, because she was ill.
> That teacher is a friend of my mother. I like her very much.

***Usually***, the rule is that:

> A defining relative clause ***usually*** comes *immediately after the noun it describes*.([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-and-non-defining))

And I underline *usually*, because there are exceptions. There are situations where you can insert other words, especially if the relative modifies a noun phrase:

> *The woman at the bar* ***who*** told me that story...

It is clearly not the bar who told you anything.

Thomas Jefferson once said

> ***That government*** *governs best* ***that*** governs least.

So you see that the NP *that government* is separated from its relative by the verb and adverb ***governs best***. But this is a sentence structure rarely used today.

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer! Very clear.

Comment: Unless you have several mothers you need a comma before *will*! ;) [*very much* work much better in post-auxiliary (i.e. pre 'main verb') position. "I very much like ..." Or you can put it at the end of the VP. But it doesn't really like being between a verb and its object. In fact nothing likes being between a verb and its object very much. A bit like being between a dog and its dinner.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  Well spotted, I put in the comma!

Comment: How about “I found that book yesterday that I thought I’d lost”?

Comment: I think the real issue might be that the original uses what can only be interpreted as a non-restrictive relative clause. Consider: "I visited that mother yesterday who couldn't make it to the surgery"

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, your examples make sense. Though I'd instinctively put "yesterday" at the beginning of the sentence...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is generally "No" because the guidance is that the relative clause refers to the phrase that is nearest to itself:

*I visited my mother yesterday who was ill.* - You will see that *who was ill* does **not** refer to the phrase that is nearest to itself. The nearest phrase is "yesterday". This sounds as if "yesterday" is a person who was ill.

*I visited my mother yesterday, which was Sunday.* Here, *which was Sunday* **does** refer to the nearest phrase - "yesterday".

In order to correct *I visited my mother yesterday who was ill.* "who was ill" needs to be moved nearer to the phrase it is qualifying:

*I visited my mother, who was ill, yesterday .*

The same applies to

*I like the teacher very much who is a friend of my mother*.

The phrase "very much" is capable of being qualified and it seems that *very much* is qualified by *who is a friend of my mother*.

Consider
*I like the teacher very much, which is more than his wife does.* (His wife only likes him a little.)

In order to correct *I like the teacher very much who is a friend of my mother* "who is a friend of my mother" needs to be moved nearer to the phrase it is qualifying:

*I **very much** like the teacher who is a friend of my mother.*

or

*I like the teacher who is a friend of my mother **very much**.*

You may think that, in *I visited my mother yesterday **who** was ill*, "who" means that only "mother" can be qualified by "**who** was ill", but the wrong position of "*who was ill*" has a much larger effect on the sentence than *who* and the result is that it is not idiomatic and sounds very wrong.

Comment: How about “I found that book yesterday that I thought I’d lost”

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Somewhat "lumpen" - it sounds wrong: a fronting time phrase is better.